# Unable to remove the lock by normal means

Tags: apt, software-center

I've been installing ubuntu restricted extras via the software center. Everything was going well at first, but then the installation process froze on 'applying changes' stage. I've had this in the past already, and usually just hitting the 'cancel' button helped, but not this time.

Obviously, the install process has placed a lock, and I couldn't issue any apt-get commands. then i've tried doing what was suggested here [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock) :

```
sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

but it seemed to me that it has only killed my X server. Okay, i've just pressed the power button on my PC, and restarted, hoping that the lock was finally off and i could reinstall the stuff.

No dice. when I open the software center, I still have one operation in process, a weird one: " Searching | Cancelling ". The 'cancel' button is either inactive, or it just does nothing. So I've become desperate and decided to write here.

How do I fix the problem? Can't install anything on a fresh ubuntu 12.04 :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error message do you get from the terminal when you run `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen


sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for anthony: 
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: also, sorry for the way i pasted it >.>

Comment: nevermind, t seems that the lock has worn off by itself O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Problem seems to have solved itself)*

> nevermind, t seems that the lock has worn off by itself O_o – Loki